# How to make a shooting mechanic with aiming?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently making a top-down 2d game and have made the basic movement, but the character doesn't turn in the direction of mouse instead then it moves it just truns in the direction of movement I dont know how to fix this.

Here is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class script1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Camera cam;

    private Vector2 moveDirection;
    Vector2 mousePos;

    Vector2 lookDir;

    void ProcessInputs()
    {
        float moveX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float moveY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        moveDirection = new Vector2(moveX, moveY); //TODO dont forget come  back later
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       ProcessInputs();

       mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;

        Move();
    }

   void Move()
   {
       rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x * moveSpeed, moveDirection.y * moveSpeed);
       float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
       rb.rotation = angle;
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome new user!  I have edited your question a bit as the title should simply be _a summary of the question_ and **not** _what you have done so far_ - that's what the post's body is for.  Good luck!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Move()` method instead of using `rb.velocity` you should use `rb.MovePosition` . Also make sure to include `Time.fixedDeltaTime` or `Time.deltaTime` so everything operates properly.

```
rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime * moveDirection);
Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
rb.rotation = angle;
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Well, it isn't exactly what I was looking for but thank you anyway.